# Printing a literal python string in octal

Tags: python, string, literals, octal

For reasons unknown I am the consumer of metadata that needs to be displayed in octal format to be used. I am trying to figure out how to represent it as an octal. Example:

```
x = "\n)\n\022foobar"
print x 

)
foobar

print repr(x)
'\n)\n\x12foobar'
```

how do i get x to print the way it was assigned, which is in octal encoding?

Answer (score 1):

You can't; that representation is lost. If you want to output "\022" then you need to either process it yourself or you need to store `"\\022"` instead.

Comment: Follow up: It's the same reason you can't tell the difference between `x = 0o22` and `x = 34` when printing `x`; both of them are (at the byte code level, created during the compilation phase) the same statement, the alternate forms of the literal are condensed into the single actual value that has no idea what literal actually created it.

Comment: thanks for the help, and i get that, but how come i cant get python to print the string in the 'encoding' i want. At the end of the day they are are the exact same byte values but simply in different representations right? Shouldnt it be possible to get python to print it in the representation I want?

Comment: No, because you didn't write `str.__repr__()`.

Comment: @KarthikSridhar: You can print *some* alternate representations (e.g. printing `repr(x)` instead of `x` as you saw), but Python doesn't directly provide the full tweakability to say which of several forms of escapes it will use for when outputting a string; all it cares about is that it outputs a correct one. You'd need to manually format the string to get your desired result, reimplementing quite a lot of Python's logic to do it. The real question is why you need this specific output formatting; odds are you're doing something wrong, or in the wrong way.